Scrapy Returning None Value, or no text at all
I am looking to scrape some local car websites to track prices so when they go on "sale", I can actually tell if its true.
Ive done the books.toscrape website. I have made a tracker for golf clubs but I can not figure out why I am getting no returns on the car tracker.
Below what I have so far:
I have tried Selectors, XPATH, Full Xpath and just cant figure it out
import scrapy
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

today = date.today()
today = str(today)


class Airdrie(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AirdrieHonda"
    allowed_domains = ["aidriehonda.ca"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.airdriehonda.ca/vehicles?refinementList=%7B%22stock_type%22%3A%5B%22NEW%22%5D%2C%22model_name%22%3A%5B%22CR-V%22%5D%7D"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        Airdrie_Car = response.css("#app > main > div.container.max-w-\[97rem\] > div > div > div.grid-cols-4.mb-64 > div > div:nth-child(2) > a.contents > div > div.inventory_footer__wspJ5.typ-label > p ::text").extract()
        Aidrie_Price = response.css("main > div.container.max-w-\[97rem\] > div > div > div.grid-cols-4.mb-64 > div > div:nth-child(2) > a.contents > div > div.flex.flex-row.flex-grow.w-full > div > div.col-span-1.text-right > span ::text").extract()
        Airdrie_DF = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[Airdrie_Car,Aidrie_Price]))).add_prefix('Col')
        Airdrie_DF = Airdrie_DF.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)
        Airdrie_DF.rename(columns={"Col0":"Type", "Col1": "Price",}, inplace = True)
        Airdrie_DF.to_csv(("AirdrieHonda" + (today) + ".csv"), encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        
        print(Airdrie_DF)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Airdrie)
process.start()


I am looking to get a list of all the current cars, models, prices and then export to a CSV.
I can figure that part out, but I just cant get the data I want extracted.

What variable, exactly, is None/empty?

@JohnGordon when I run it, I am looking in the terminal as to what its doing and printing the variables. Airdrie_Car  returns "None". Ive tried Selectors, X paths, different levels of the selectors and xpaths and nothing works.

This code doesn't print Airdrie_Car at all.  So how are you printing it?

@JohnGordon I had it in there before. Printed a few lines of ("**"*20) then print(Airdrie_Car) and "None" comes back.

Maybe scrapy playwright will work better for it?

That just means your selectors are wrong.

@wRAR that's what I figured. But I've gone through from the highest class, to the lowest. It also returns "0 pages scraped 0 returns"

Not sure what do you mean by that, sorry.

Im still playing around and can not get anything really to print. I am playing in the scrapy shell. Trying to get all the classes, or anything to print and it just returns "[]".

So I am starting to think that the website prevents scraping. Even using the scrapy shell, I cant fetch the website. It gives me a 403. I have tried a couple dealships, same thing. But then tried a few other sites and had no problem.

So for anyone that reads this and has the same issue. I figured it out. Certain websites prevent you from using bots to access their website and scraping data.
Its easy to work around. You can Google "Googles User Agent". Then use their user agent, update the settings.py file in your scrapy project then it will bypass the restriction.

So for anyone that reads this and has the same issue. I figured it out. Certain websites prevent you from using bots to access their website and scraping data.
Its easy to work around. You can Google "Googles User Agent". Then use their user agent, update the settings.py file in your scrapy project then it will bypass the restriction.
I have tested it on a few websites. Before I would get "0 pages scraped" with no returns. It turns out it was a 403 error (being prevented from accessing the site). After updating the USER_AGENT to Googles, there are no issues.
